# How to configure artifactory for private maven repository

Tags: maven, artifactory

after auto generating the settings.xml file in artifactory and deploying the file to the ~/.m2/ directory I am concerned that the file does not reference a repo where dependencies .i.e. junit are located.

where do you find a reference or test to validate maven is using artifactory for dependency management?

Answer (score 0):

Build your project with Maven, look at the log file: You see where the dependencies are downloaded from.